# How do change time of execute an action in a service?

Tags: android, service

I have a problem with a service on Android.

This service does a synchronization to my service, I want the user to select the time of this synchronization, for it I have a preference when the user can select the range of time for synchronize.

When user select a range of sinchronization, in a listener, I stop the service and start again, but the service is to execute one more to time and my idea is that service is to destroy and create this service again but a new range time.

Class of Service

```
public class ServicioSincronizacion extends Service {
private Timer mTimer = null;
int tiempo;
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    tiempo = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("frecuencia_sincronizacion", "0"))*1000 ;
    this.mTimer = new Timer();
    if(tiempo!=0){
        this.mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                new TimerTask(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        sincronizar(tiempo);
                    }
                }
                , 0, tiempo);
        }
    }

private void sincronizar(int tiempo){
    Log.i("Backgraung","Create a background with time "+tiempo);
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Log.i("Backgraung","Start background whit time "+tiempo);

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("Backgraung","Destroy background whit time "+tiempo);
    stopSelf();
}
}
```

Call first time, when user's loaging, after of the sinchronitation

```
 sincronizarTodo(mActivity, new AsyncICallBackFinalizado() {
                                @Override
                                public void finalizar() {
                                    Intent service = new Intent(mActivity, ServicioSincronizacion.class);
                                    startService(service);
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }});
                        }
```

And I restart here

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    switch (key){
        case "frecuencia_sincronizacion":
            Intent service = new Intent(getActivity(), ServicioSincronizacion.class);
            getActivity().stopService(service);
            getActivity().startService(service);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: to clarify; you want this service to run, in the background, at a time specified by the user, to do some network sync?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: you may want to use something like JobScheduler/AlarmManager/Firebase Job Scheduler, or a composite of them like Evernote's library I use (did not make it) https://github.com/evernote/android-job